# Search in joint table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search, has-and-belongs-to-many

i need some help to put a search field on my view.

I got a families table, and each family got 0-n books. I want to make a search that only families of a specific book are show.

Right now i am using ransack for some other simple searches:

Controler:

```
class FamiliesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @search = Family.search(params[:q])
    @families = @search.result    

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @families }
    end
  end
```

model:

```
class Family < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :names
  has_and_belongs_to_many :books, :join_table => "books_families"
  has_and_belongs_to_many :races, :join_table => "families_races"

  attr_accessible :descr, :nome, :book_ids, :race_ids

  validates :nome, uniqueness: true, presence: true
end
```

View:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Filter for families</legend>
  <%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :nome, "Name: " %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :nome_cont, :class => "search-field"%>
    </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Search" %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</fieldset>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th><%= sort_link(@search, :nome, "Name") %></th>
    <th>Books</th>
    <th>Descr</th>
  </tr>
(...)
    <td>
      <ol type="disc">
        <% family.books.each do |book| %>
          <li> <%= book.nome %> </li>
        <% end %>
      </ol>
    </td>
(...)
```

What should i do?

Comment: So, you want the user to search for a book, and your code to return all families that are associated with that book, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution. its a simple 2 line thing:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :books_id_eq, "Livro:" %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :books_id_eq, Book.order(:nome), :id, :nome, :include_blank => "Todos" %> 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with ransack, but your query should be achievable with SQL. I don't know your all of your table/field names, but something like this should work.

```
@families = Family.where("families.id IN(SELECT books_families.family_id FROM 
                          books_families WHERE books_families.book_id IN( 
                          SELECT books.id FROM books WHERE books.title LIKE(?)))",
                          "%" + params[:q] + "%")
```

Comment: I didnt test it till now. Nope, didnt work:
>> @search
!! #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near ",": syntax error: SELECT "families".* FROM "families"  WHERE (id IN(SELECT family_id FROM books_families WHERE book_id IN( SELECT book_id FROM books WHERE nome LIKE(nome))), )>
And i just notice that i dont know how to do the same query in sql

Comment: I reviewed my code and it appears there were a couple of syntax errors. I have corrected them. This SQL assumes that you have a table called `families` with an `id` column. A table called `books`, with at least an `id` and `title` column, and a table that links the two called `books_families`, with a `book_id` column and a `family_id` column. If these fields/tables have different names on your end, you can either change them yourself in the query, or post them here and I can help you.